# System Authentication Redirection in Microsite - Can not login

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page

I selected the "System Authentication Redirection" option for security for one of the child landing page in the microsite of my Exact Target account . It redirects me to main account login but I am not able to login in with my account username and password . It gives an error for incorrect login/password/URL. What credentials we need to use here ?

Comment: Should be the normal account credentials.  Do you know if you have an enterprise 2.0 account?

Comment: @KellyJAndrews    Thanks. I am not very sure but from the all the features we have in our account I think we do have the enterprise 2.0 account.